# FATAL: parse 'conf/gitolite.conf-compiled.pm' failed: No such file or directory

Tags: github

After I do `git push origin master`, I get this error:

> FATAL: parse 'conf/gitolite.conf-compiled.pm' failed: No such file or directory
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

This never happened before, and I don't know why. Can someone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check your `git remote -v` output: chances are, it is *not* https://github.com/..., meaning it has nothing to do with GitHub.

[Gitolite is an authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/overview.html) that you install on Git repository hosting server of your choosing.

The error message you see could be the result of a system update on the server, [as in this case](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitolite/bgHU9XwxW6A).

The [OP Aries](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9018842/aries) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55623914/fatal-parse-conf-gitolite-conf-compiled-pm-failed-no-such-file-or-directory/55624902?noredirect=1#comment97964315_55624902):

> Someone updated the remote server recently, that may cause the problem.

Comment: After I do ```git remote -v```, I got   
codecommit-origin       https://xxx.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/origin (fetch)
codecommit-origin       https:/xxx.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/origin (push)  
heroku https://git.heroku.com/xxx.git (fetch)   
heroku https://git.heroku.com/xxx.git (push)  
origin git@xxx (fetch)
origin git@xxx (push)

Comment: @Aries Then the Gitolite part is hosted on `xxx`, the default server '`origin`' you are pushing to. If it was working before, something must have changed on it: the server OS version, the Gitolite version, the Git version, ...

Comment: Oh ok, I think I know what happened. Someone updated the remote server recently, that may cause the problem. Thank you so much!